# BehaviorSubject with Typescript gives error if initialized with null as default value

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have an interface called **SelectedNodeInfoInterface**. I have a BehaviorSubject which I would like to initialize with null and after some operation completes, or method is called i pass new value (.next(value)) on it. It used to work fine but I enabled

> strict:true

in my typescript config and since then it started to give me error. If I disable that flag, it compiles without problem and works as expected. However, I would like to keep strict mode enabled.

Code looks like this

```
export class SharedLinkedDetailsService {
selectedAccounts$: BehaviorSubject<SelectedNodeInfoInterface>;
constructor() {
  this.selectedAccounts$ = new BehaviorSubject(null);

 }

accountsSelected(selectedNode: SelectedNodeInfoInterface) {
  this.selectedAccounts$.next(selectedNode);
}

export interface SelectedNodeInfoInterface {
  selectedAccounts?: string | string[];
  highlightEdges?: boolean;
 }
```

> Type 'BehaviorSubject' is not assignable to type
>   'BehaviorSubject'.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Share the code where you're initializing the BehaviorSubject

Comment: looks like you have defined your property like  BehaviorSubject<null> so SelectedNodeInfoInterface is not type of null

do something like 

selectedNodeInfoInterface = new BehaviorSubject<SelectedNodeInfoInterface>(null);

Comment: @KarthigeyanVellasamy - If I do as you are suggesting - it gives another error - Argument of type 'null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SelectedNodeInfoInterface'.

Comment: @Teebo - Added code above

Comment: tried BehaviorSubject<SelectedAccountType | null>?

Comment: you can suppress the error for that code.
Add // @ts-ignore above this.selectedAccounts$ = new BehaviorSubject(null);

Comment: @Allabakash yeah but you can suppress errors for anything. What you want is valid types.

Comment: @seesharper - Tried that as well. 

Type 'BehaviorSubject<null>' is not assignable to type 'BehaviorSubject<SelectedAccountType>'.
  Types of property 'observers' are incompatible.
    Type 'Observer<null>[]' is not assignable to type 'Observer<SelectedAccountType>[]'.
      Type 'Observer<null>' is not assignable to type 'Observer<SelectedAccountType>'.
        Type 'SelectedAccountType' is not assignable to type 'null'.
          Type 'SelectedNodeInfoInterface' is not assignable to type 'null'

Comment: @Allabakash - I would prefer to actually fix it rather than suppressing it :)

Comment: As @seesharper suggested <ObjectType | null> should work...

Comment: There seem to be more types involved than your posted code covers. What are the `observers`? Their types would also need to reflect the type: Observer<SelectedAccountType | null>.

Comment: @seesharper - It gives me the error even if I don't have any observers. Pretty sure its some small thing I am missing.

Answer (score 24):

Try this:

```
export class SharedLinkedDetailsService {
  selectedAccounts$: BehaviorSubject<SelectedAccountType | null>;
  constructor() {
    this.selectedAccounts$ = new BehaviorSubject<SelectedAccountType | null>(null);

  }

  accountsSelected(selectedNode: SelectedNodeInfoInterface) {
    this.selectedAccounts$.next(selectedNode);
  }
```

The point about strict mode is that null and undefined types are not allowed as alternatives to a defined type. So in that case, if you define a type where the value may also be null or undefined, you have to explicitly declare that possibility. The pipe tells typescript that the type may be either `SelectedAccountType` or `null`. I hope that makes it clear!

Comment: This seems to be working. Doesn't give error anymore. Can you please explain this as well. I understand you created a variable with union type - BehaviorSubject<SelectedNodeInfoInterface| null> which can accept both SelectedNodeInfoInterface and null. Can you please explain what you did in constructor and why you had to caste there?

Comment: Added explanation - note I am not 'casting' when calling the constructor. I am providing a generic parameter to tell typescript that the type used by the class may be either null or SelectedNodeInfoInterface.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:  Another way to set type

`this.selectedAccounts$ = new BehaviorSubject({} as SelectedNodeInfoInterface);`

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this

```
selectedAccounts = new BehaviorSubject(null);
```

Out side of the constructor, the second approach would be like the below.
I am not sure if typing it like the following would work

```
selectedAccounts = new BehaviorSubject<TheTypeHere>(InitialValueOfType)
```

Please try the second code snippet.

Comment: First one errors out in next method call with - Argument of type 'SelectedNodeInfoInterface' is not assignable to parameter of type 'null'.

Comment: For 2 ) SelectedNoInterface is a type, but its being referred as value here.

Comment: It's not valid typescript

Comment: it gives another error - Argument of type 'null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SelectedNodeInfoInterface'.

Comment: The second approach would only work when you pass a valid initial value of that type

Answer (score 0):

You need to type the behavior subject

```
this.selectedAccounts$ = new BehaviorSubject<SelectedNodeInfoInterface>(null);
```

or

```
this.selectedAccounts$ = new BehaviorSubject(null as SelectedNodeInfoInterface);
```

or

```
this.selectedAccounts$ = new BehaviorSubject(null) as BehaviorSubject<SelectedNodeInfoInterface>;
```

All 3 will work but I would go with number 1.

Personally I would not initialise it in the constructor but just assign a new behavior subject to the property directly.

```
export class SharedLinkedDetailsService {
  selectedAccounts$ = new BehaviorSubject<SelectedNodeInfoInterface>(null);

  accountsSelected(selectedNode: SelectedNodeInfoInterface) {
    this.selectedAccounts$.next(selectedNode);
  }
```

Comment: First one fails with - Argument of type null is not assignable to parameter of type SelectedNodeInfoInterface

Comment: Second - Conversion of null to type could be a mistake because neither type sufficienctly overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert expression to unknown. If I convert it to unknown like -      this.selectedAccounts$ = new BehaviorSubject((null as unknown  as SelectedNodeInfoInterface)            it works

Comment: Then your type SelectedNodeInfoInterface doesn't allow null

Comment: With the first one, you need to pass an initial value of that type, if that type is an object, pass that object with initial values instead of null

Comment: We need to see the definition for SelectedAccountType

Comment: @AdrianBrand - Added definition in original post

Comment: @Vatsal, then pass an object with an empty string and an initial boolean value for the props confirming to your interface instead of null, I wonder why you downvoted my answer tho

Comment: So what is SelectedAccountType then?

Comment: @AdrianBrand - I am sorry, that's a typo.. Not sure how it came. Fixing it

Comment: @Teebo - I didn't downvote. I was trying to see myself that who did that.

Comment: Just use undefined instead of null

Comment: @AdrianBrand - This works. Why I didn't think of this is beyond me. I tried to call it without arguments, but it expects one argument. I never thought that that argument can be undefined. Thank you,